# how to implement facebook realtime notification using c#

Tags: c#

I want to implement a notification feature i.e. user gets notification just like facebook when database is updated. I want to implement this feature in c#, can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: show us what you've tried we wont code for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) for real-time web features.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events), grouping connections, and authorization.